# No compila Repositorio Local - Maven

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

Estoy usando Maven con Eclipse y tengo configurado un repositorio de fuentes en el pom.xml. En mi .m2 están todas las dependencias incluidos jars de otros proyectos que debo de utilizar (antes estaban como lib).

Mi problema es que da error al compilar en aquellas clases java que hacen referencia a métodos de clases incluidas en dichos jars.

Por ejemplo:

> ...claseMundo.java:[586,91] incompatible types: ....

Cuando en el fichero pom tengo algo como esto:

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>es.proyectomundo</groupId> 
  <artifactId>ProyectoMundo</artifactId> 
  <version>1.0</version> 
</dependency>
```

¿A qué se debe si las dependencias están en .m2?

Comment: Sin información de tu fichero pom.xml es imposible determinar qué puede estar ocurriendo

Comment: Hola Hector, en el pom.xml hay dependencias añadidas de librerias locales, por ejemplo:<dependency>
   <groupId>es.proyectomundo</groupId>
   <artifactId>ProyectoMundo</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency> Dentro de ProyectoMundo.jar existe una clase con un metodo utilizado y ahí es cuando falla. Muchas gracias

Comment: Me refiero a que deberías añadir el código de la inyección de dependencias de tu POM en la pregunta. Editándola

Comment: Si son librerías propias ( desarrolladas de manera privada ) deberás agregarlas manualmente a tu repositorio local. Muestra el Pom completo y en esa dirección de la dependencia, mira si tienes el jar y el Pom apunte a mismo groupId

Comment: La librerías propias estan agregadas manualmente en el .m2 con el jar, el Pom y con el mismo groupId. Sin embargo, además del error al compilar, al situarte encima de la línea con error indica "configure build path..." Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que cuando crear tus propias librerias en un repositorio de Maven tiene dos opciones para poder usarlas.

1 .- Instalandolas, ejecutando el siguiente comando:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile = c:\carpeta\al\archivo\claseMundo.jar -DgroupId=es.proyectomundo -DartifactId=ProyectoMundo-Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Y ahora si agregas tu dependencia en el POM:

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>es.proyectomundo</groupId> 
  <artifactId>ProyectoMundo</artifactId> 
  <version>1.0</version> 
</dependency>
```

2 .- Puedes hacerlo manualmente al declarar la dependencia en tu POM pero debes hacer referencia a la ruta completa de tu carpeta usando el scoope System.

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>es.proyectomundo</groupId> 
  <artifactId>ProyectoMundo</artifactId> 
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>c:\carpeta\al\archivo\claseMundo.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

O tambien...

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>es.proyectomundo</groupId> 
  <artifactId>ProyectoMundo</artifactId> 
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>c:\carpeta\al\archivo\claseMundo.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Comment: el scope system esta desaconsejado por si alguien tuviera curiosidad, lleva años que maven esta advirtiendo que en versiones futuras vana  deshabilitar esa funcionalidad